# Selecting rows in a long dataframe based on a short list

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm sure this should be easier to do than the way I know how to do it.
I'd like to apply fields from a short dataframe back into a long one based on matching a common factor.

Example short dataframe, list of valid cases:

```
$ptid (factor) values 1,2,3,4,5...20
```

$valid 1/0 (to represent true/false; variable through ptid)

long dataframe has 15k rows, each level of $ptid will have several thousand rows

I want to apply $valid onto those rows when the it is 1/true from the list above

The way I *know* how to do it is to loop through each row of long dataframe, but this is horribly inelegant and also slow.

I have a niggling feeling there is a much better way with dply or similar and I'd really like to learn how.

Comment: Please show few lines of each dataset and the expected result based on that

Comment: Check `merge`. And also add a reproducible example (It will help you to understand-solve yourself exactly your problem by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Worked this out based on the comments, thank you Colonel.

combination_dataset <- Merge(short_dataframe, long_dataframe) worked (very quickly).

Thanks to those who commented.